# vue + webpack: SyntaxError: invalid range in character class

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am working on webpack 4.29.3 and vue.js 2.6.3. I just tried to create a simple hello world project with vue js and webpack. I expected `index.html` to be rendered well. I get the error, though: SyntaxError: invalid range in character class which is really weird because I don't do anything with regular expression. that's why I am not sure which part to fix it.

vue-first.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Getting Started</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="app">
     {{ message }}
   </div>
   <script src="todo.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/vue-first.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'todo.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-first",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.3"
  }
}
```

the full error message (from Safari) :

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class
    RegExp (todo.js:7:3226)
    (anonymous function) (todo.js:7:3226)
    (anonymous function) (todo.js:7:63703)
    n (todo.js:1:115)
    (anonymous function) (todo.js:7:63775)
    n (todo.js:1:115)
    (anonymous function) (todo.js:1:904)
    Global Code (todo.js:1:912)
```

for more detail, you can checkout my [Github](https://github.com/inherithandle/vue-webpack-simple-project).

Comment: Do you get the error from webpack or from the browser? What source code line does it refer to? (The error reads like a regex syntax problem, but there are no regular expressions in the code posted here.)

Comment: from browsers. `npm run build` and `npx webpack` works fine. it happens in the line 7 from `todo.js`. I've listed the full error message. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in `todo.js`? (No such file on your github repo.) And enable map files for your JS so the browser can give you the pre-minification/packing source code reference.

Comment: it is an output from webpack. it is minified code that contains Vue.js and vue-first.js. that's why I didn't pushed it on Github. but I've pushed it now for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to, at the very least, specify the build [`mode`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/) and tell Webpack to use its built-in optimizations and add an [`alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) for Vue.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',

  entry: './src/js/vue-first.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'todo.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: it makes sense that I need to specify the build `mode`. but I don't know why we need the `resolve` part. I imported Vue in vue-first.js. I think that makes Webpack add up vue-first.js and vue.js into todo.js. and I don't have the directory `vue/dist`.

Comment: @inherithandle Without the `alias`, you would have to type in the fully qualified name like `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'`. It simply is there for importing or requiring certain modules more easily.

Comment: `and I don't have the directory vue/dist` NPM creates that for you when you run `npm install`) -- Have a look at `node_modules/vue/dist/...`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. now I understand what's wrong with. I thought the ES6 import statement would work like the `require` function in node.js and would automatically find the `Vue` instasnce from `node_modules`.

Comment: hmmm.. I thought it would work. it doesn't. Could you help me out? I tried `resolve` and some import statements like `import Vue from vue/dist/vue.js`, `import Vue from 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'`, `'./vue/dist/vue.js'`, `'./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js'`. they all don't work for me.

Comment: @inherithandle Either `resolve.alias` or `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'` should totally work. Could you push the latest changes to GitHub repo again?

Comment: I just pushed it.

Comment: Well, I pulled them in, and it seems to work just fine for me. Did you add the `mode` on the `webpack.config.js` though?

Comment: adding `mode` make it work. but i don't know what `mode` do for me at this point.

Comment: Have a read on the [docs for Webpack `mode`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/). It simply tells Webpack to use specific optimization modes.